# button highlighting using keyboard keys

Tags: java, swing

I've created some buttons in java and when it is clicked a new form should show up.I want to use the arrow keys to select buttons and space bar to click it.
My code works when I run the project from an ide or cmd.But when a runnable jar file is created using eclipse the buttons are not getting highlighted when I press the keyboard keys.I am able to use only the mouse.Where could the problem be?

Answer (score 3):

> My code works when I run the project from an ide or cmd.

So how are you doing this? I would guess you are using a KeyListener. A KeyListener only works when a component has focus and I would guess your buttons don't have focus so the code doesn't work. In general you should NOT use a KeyListener Swing was designed to be used with [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

So one way to solve this is to create a custom Action for tabbing forward and backwards and then bind these actions to the panel containing the buttons. The `Key Binding` can work even when the component doesn't have focus. The code would be something like:

```
InputMap im = panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
String rightText = "RIGHT";
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(rightText), rightText);
panel.getActionMap().put(rightText, new AbstractAction()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().focusNextComponent();
    }
});
```

Another way is to use the [KeyboardFocusManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#intro). The `KeyboardFocusManager` manages focus traversal. The default focus traversal keys are Tab and Shift-Tab.

If you want to also use the arrow keys, then you need to add these KeyStrokes to the focus manager. So for each component you want to change you would do:

```
    Set<AWTKeyStroke> set = new HashSet<AWTKeyStroke>( button.getFocusTraversalKeys(
        KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS ) );
    set.add( KeyStroke.getKeyStroke( "RIGHT" ) );
    button.setFocusTraversalKeys(
        KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, set );
```

The first approach works for all components on a panel. The second approach for individual components.

Comment: Yea i am using a key listener.when i press a arrow key the next corresponding button will get focus and ill change its icon to show that it has got highlighted. Initially the first button will have the focus. The problem is when a runnable jar is run the first button is not getting highlighted.

Comment: @srinivas `Yea i am using a key listener.` - and I gave you two better solutions.

Comment: It works now. I Created the jar from net beans.I didnt make any changes to the code. I dont understand why it didnt work when exported from eclipse.Ill try these two solutions as well!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the mnemonic property of your button to the key you want.

```
myJButton.setMnemonic(...);
```

Comment: There are 5 buttons and initially the first one will be selected. Left and right arrow keys are used to cycle through the buttons.

Comment: I don't exactly know what is the key code for arrow keys. But if you make the GUI on NetBeans, the editor will do that for you

Comment: i tried creating two buttons but i am not able to use the arrow keys to select the buttons

Comment: Then that should be by tab

Comment: yea tab key works.what changes should i make to use it with the arrow keys

Comment: I would make the program with four buttons and edit my answer with that. Aaj shaam tak update kar dunga