# JDialog: Remove titlebar, keep border

Tags: java, swing, border, jdialog

Is it possible to remove the title bar from a JDialog, but keeping the border?

The base SSCCE looks like this:

```
package test;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SSCCE extends JFrame {
    private JDialog dialog;

    public SSCCE() {
        dialog = new JDialog();
        dialog.setSize(100, 100);
        dialog.add(new JList<>(new String[] { "One", "Two", "Three" }));
        dialog.setUndecorated(true);

        setSize(300, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void showDialog() {
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                SSCCE ex = new SSCCE();
                ex.setVisible(true);
                ex.showDialog();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Running it I see this:

[image: JDialog with full titlebar and borders]

But I don't want the title bar on the JDialog. The standard answer is to use `setUndecorated(true)`. But then I lose the window borders as well, and I don't want that. Looks like this:

[image: JDialog with no titlebar and no borders]

What I want is something like this mockup:

[image: JDialog with just the borders]

How do I achieve that?

**EDIT:**

I tried going with one of the LaF borders, but I'm getting some strange results. Just for testing I went with "RootPane.errorDialogBorder" and expected to get a fat red border around my dialog. But instead I got this:

[image: JDialog with LAF border]

That looks to me like the unfocused version of the "RootPane.frameBorder" border. Why did I get that one instead?

Comment: *"Is it possible to remove the title bar from a JDialog, but keeping the border?"* The short answer is generally, no. Some Look and Feels supply there own frame boards, some use the OS, so it further complicates the issues...

Comment: @Tobbe add border to panel and add panel to jdialog

Comment: @FastSnail I don't know how to create that kind of border though. It needs to somehow be based on the current LaF border style. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It needs to somehow be based on the current LaF border style.

As you already know it is not possible to use the actual dialog/frame border.

Seems like you need a Border to highlight the popup so it stands out from the text field. I think the closest you can come is to use a Border that is defined by the LAF. For example you might be able to use the "TitledBorder.border" property defined in the `UIManager` it is a simple Border but appears to be slightly different for each LAF.

Take a look at [UIManager Default](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/). It displays all the Border for each LAF

Comment: Thanks for the link to the UIManager Default application, very useful! But actually trying to use one of the borders I got some weird results, please see my edit to my original question.

Comment: @Tobbe, I don't know why the Border color is different then what the UIManager Defaults shows. The code for painting the Border is found in the `MetalBorders` class, but I couldn't track down where the actual color is determined.

Comment: And it's not just the colors, it's that inner line as well! It's all very strange.